# Filtered Questions page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

The page for filters, https://stackexchange.com/filters shows Oops Panda at present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My fault - fix incoming. A major change to how StackExchange.com gets and uses the list of sites is in-progress (lots of debt cleanup), this one got by.

Ultimately, this is a deep dependency in deploying proper HTTPS for all sites. It's going to be a fun, really, really, really, really, really long blog post.

Comment: Not enough really, really. :-D