# Icons are missing in tag subscriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed

Icons are missing in tag subscriptions:

[image]

Comment: @PatrickHofman - related, but not the same. This is about emailed tag subscriptions, not the se.com site.

Comment: @Oded http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283428/icons-of-meta-se-and-stack-apps-have-gone-missing#comment918743_283428

Answer (score 3):

Not anymore, they are not.

We had a bug that was live overnight. It has since been fixed.